# How to find Latitude and longitude of Polygon shape edges?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How to collect latitude and longitude of each edges of Polygon shape which we are drawing by google drawing API. Please help me by putting me in the perfect path to collect edges of Polygon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Region Drawing System</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing,geometry&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
    var infoWindow;
    var contentString;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(42.397, -100.000),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ]
        },
            polygonOptions :{
                editable: true,
                draggable: true
        }
    });
     drawingManager.setMap(map);
     google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'click', showNewPath); // Passing drawingManager object is a good idea to collect edges of Polygon ?
     infoWindow =   new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    }
    function showNewPath() {
            var contentString = " " //How to collect the edges of Polygon ?
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.setPosition();  // How to specify the position for each edge ?
            infowindow.open(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center> 
        <h1> Region Drawing System</h1>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:400px ; width:800px"></div>
    <hr/>
        <div id="panel">
            <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
            <input type="button" value="Look UP" >
        </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show you've done some of your own research, don't just ask for 'sample code', otherwise your question is likely to get closed

Comment: I am really sorry for the mistake I have done. In future I will never let it to happen.

Comment: possible duplicat of [Array contains latitude and longitude of a polygon in Google maps drawingManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487751/array-contains-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-drawingmanager/19493137#19493137)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By The following code. Anyone can find the Lattitude and Longitude of the Polygon which we have drawn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Region Drawing System</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing,geometry&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
    var polygonShape = [];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth : 450});
    var contentString;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(42.397, -100.000),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ]
        },
            polygonOptions :{
                editable: true,
                draggable: true
        }
    });
     drawingManager.setMap(map);
     google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (e) {
          var vert = e.getPath(); //In the method we could get the vertices of the polygon which we have drawn.
          var clat = 0; // To display the infowindow.
      var clng = 0; // To display the infowindow.
      var contents = '</br><label><b>Region Name : </b></label><input type="text" size="20" id="region_name"/></br><label align="top"><b>Description : </b></label><textarea id="region_desc" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea><br/><input type="button" value="Save Region" onclick="getPointInfo(polygonShape);"/><br/>';
      vert.forEach(function(xy, i) {
          clat = xy.lat();
          clng = xy.lng();
          });
          infoWindow.setContent(contents);
          infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(clat,clng));
          infoWindow.open(map);
    });});
     infoWindow =   new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center> 
        <h1> Region Drawing System</h1>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:400px ; width:800px"></div>
    <hr/>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have fun with the above code.