# How to get latitude and longitude of all polygon points in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a user draw a polygon on the map. Once they complete the polygon I can get the coordinates of each point to display on the page. If they move the polygon after completing it, the coordinates will update with the movement. Is there a way I can break this up to show the latitude and longitude of all points the user creates separately and update with movement?

Currently it displays like this:

Coordinates

(37.71859032558816, -121.563720703125),(38.10862766432127, -120.1904296875),(36.77409249464195, -120.08056640625),(36.2354121683998, -117.784423828125),(35.951329861522666, -119.8828125)

I would like to break it up and have it display something like this:

Shape 1:

Latitude:

Point 1: 37.71859032558816

Point 2: 38.10862766432127

Point 3: 36.77409249464195

Point 4: 36.2354121683998

Point 5: 35.951329861522666

Longitude:

Point 1: -121.563720703125

Point 2: -120.1904296875

Point 3: -120.08056640625

Point 4: -117.784423828125

Point 5: -119.8828125

Here is what I currently have:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e)
{
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    shapes.add(e);
    // getPath(): return value: MVCArray<LatLng>
    // getArray(): return value: Array<LatLng>
    var arrayOne = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
    document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = arrayOne;

    // var latitude = ?
    // var longitude = ?

    document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
    document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = longitude;

    google.maps.event.addListener(e.overlay.getPath(), 'set_at', function()
    {
        // getPath(): return value: MVCArray<LatLng>
        // getArray(): return value: Array<LatLng>
        var arrayOne = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
        document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = arrayOne;

        // var latitude = ?
        // var longitude = ?

        document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = longitude;
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(e.overlay.getPath(), 'insert_at', function()
    {
        // getPath(): return value: MVCArray<LatLng>
        // getArray(): return value: Array<LatLng>
        var arrayOne = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
        document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = arrayOne;

        // var latitude = ?
        // var longitude = ?

        document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = longitude;
      });
});
```

I have come across a few things such as getAt(), geometry.location.lat(), and LatLng class, but I have not had any luck. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a solution to my problem can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488826

Modifying the code a little bit allows me to achieve my desired output

```
var polygonBounds = e.overlay.getPath();
var testArray = [];

for (var a = 0; a < polygonBounds.length; a++)
{
    testArray.push(polygonBounds.getAt(a).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(a).lng());
}

var latPoint = 1;
var lngPoint = 1;


for (var b = 0; b < testArray.length; b += 2)
{
    document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML += ("Point " + [latPoint] + ": " + testArray[b] + "<br /><br />");
    latPoint++;
}

for (var c = 0; c < testArray.length; c += 2)
{
    document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML += ("Point " + [lngPoint] + ": " + testArray[c] + "<br /><br />");
    lngPoint++;
}
```

Now I just have to get it to update if the polygon is moved or modified